# Switch case won't work with my while loop?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

hey im a very rookie coder, and i was trying to create an average calculator program. However once I use this code, it skips my switch case and goes immediately to my default case. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

class AverageCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ramim = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalToAverage;
        int counter = 1;
        int ans;
        String ans2;
        int tally = 0;

        System.out.print("How many different inputs do you want to put in?: ");
        totalToAverage = ramim.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your input # is " + totalToAverage + ".");

        while (counter <= totalToAverage) {
            System.out.print("Enter number " + counter + ":");
            counter++;
            ans = ramim.nextInt();
            tally = ans + tally;
        }

        System.out.println("You have entered " + --counter + " numbers." + "Your total is " + tally + ".");

        System.out.println("Would you like to find your average?");
        ans2 = ramim.nextLine();

        switch (ans2) {
        case "yes":
            System.out.println("note: dont worry about this part yet");
            break;

        case "no":
            System.out.println("Alright.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter yes or no only. :)");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ramim.nextLine();` twice to get String input after getting int input. This is because `ramim.nextInt();` does not read the last `ENTER` character you type. So do something like:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to find your average?");
ramim.nextLine();
ans2 = ramim.nextLine();
```

Comment: When code behaves as per its contract, it's not a bug.

Comment: Just realized that. Fixed it.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but if you see a question like this it's worth trying to find a duplicate to flag it as instead of writing an answer - saves you time, and means you can write answers to more interesting questions.

Comment: @hnefatl Meh, need the reputation from accepted and upvoted answers.

Comment: @Ivar Please explain.

Comment: @Ivar Okay then. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: @Ivar Should I then do something like my comment for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722653/java-knapsack-nullpointerexception)?

Comment: @Ivar I did write that myself. Can't flag as duplicate because daily limit is 10 and I've used those already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168510/discussion-between-raymo111-and-ivar).